# oracle index (to_date(datecolumn,'YYYY-MM-DD')) vs (column,'YYYY-MM-DD') is same?

Tags: indexing

create index (to_date(datecolumn,'YYYY-MM-DD'))
vs.
create index (column,'YYYY-MM-DD')

what's the two meaning, are they same functionality?

explain the two expression